# Facing issue when i try setup a AEM environment locally

Tags: adobe, aem-6, experience-manager

[Hare is image you can see a error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhmfY.png)
I am Developer. I want to learn Adobe Experience Manager (AEM). I am trying to setup environment locally but when I quickstart jar file the cmd window was popup and the error are appred so who knows how to solve this issue please help us.

Comment: You may want to read [ask]